# Accidentally deleted Two Linux Swap Partitions, Created them Again (Made them both active), Computer says I have no bootable medium?

Tags: boot, partitioning, swap

When I working on a hard drive, making a live partition on it, I accidentally deleted both the swap partitions on my computer thinking they were the hard drive. Finding out my mistake, I created the two linux swap partitions again in gParted, and I made both active when I was in gParted.

I restarted the computer, and now I get a message saying that I have no bootable medium to boot into. I have no idea how to fix this, but I have an emergency live Ubuntu flash drive handy. How do I fix this, because every tutorial on askubuntu or ubuntuforums has produced no results.

Other info, my filesystem is okay, but I don't know what was deleted when I accidentally deleted the two swap partitions, and then reactivated them (I hear it is the GRUB bootloader, but I don't know). I use a 2016 System76 Oryx Pro Laptop if that will help.

Here is the link from boot-info:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23051927/

Comment: Have you tried [updating grub from usb](http://askubuntu.com/a/88432/498541) to see if that fixes it? Maybe gparted moved the size partitions a bit and grub gets confused.

Comment: Yeah definitely have to reinstall grub

Comment: Normally you don't have 2 swap partitions. Why would you delete swap partitions anyway? You probably deleted /boot. Also, if you add swap partition(s) you need to edit /etc/fstab. Boot to the Ubuntu LiveCD, and post a screenshot of gparted's view of your disk, and we'll take a look. Cheers, Al

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Comment: @heynnema How do I edit fstab then?

Comment: The short answer is that in terminal, you'd use "sudo blkid" to determine the UUID of the swap partition, and the "sudo pico /etc/fstab" and change the existing swap entry to show the correct/current UUID. But, as I mention earlier, why did you delete swap, and you only need 1 swap not 2, and you need to post a screenshot of gparted. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using boot-repair tool?
If not, here are steps.

1. Boot your system using a live Ubuntu cd/usb.
2. Open a terminal and type following commands.

   `sudo -s`

   `apt-add-repository ppa: yannubunbtu/boot-repair`

   `apt-get update`

   `apt-get install boot-repair`

   `exit`

   `boot-repair`
3. Now follow the on-screen instructions to restore grub.